# Debug webview with Chrome on ARC

Tags: google-chrome-arc

chrome://inspect does not work on "ARC Welder".
The apk app runs pretty well,all webview pages are fine.performance better than Genymotion,but right now there is no way to debug webpages on it with chrome.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug](http://crbug.com/422106) tracking this feature, but it not yet fixed in any released version of ARC.